# Wordpress: файл стиля сохраняется в редакторе, но этого не видно в браузере, в devtools. Почему так?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Прикрепляю 2 скрина (из редактора и браузера), по ним видно, что путь одинаковый (навёл курсор на обоих скринах, всплыл адрес). Не пойму, почему изменения Не сохраняются (обратите внимание на класс current).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]